# Usage hints for C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

What is the source of these usage hints for methods in Visual Studio? I can not figure out where these originate?!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "originate"? These are examples. They are nowhere to be found in your code if that's what this is.

Comment: It's just meta-info on functions/types/members/whatever. You can add your own usage hints by adding summary tags above methods/classes/structs/functions/members and so on too. Just type `///` above any of them and it should autofill summary tags that you can use to create your own.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/

Comment: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/91c17adc183487dd3e7a41e90430c286a7add7db/nuget/SQLite-net/SQLite-net.csproj#L42

Answer (score 2):

I commented earlier, but just for more detail, those usage hints are born from `/// <summary>` tags being added to methods/classes/etc in the code files.

It's pretty standard across `.net` and API's to add summary tags to classes and functions to give you some sense of what it's supposed to be used for (often with varying results though).

If you want to define your own usage hints all you have to do is add the following above whatever you want a hint on (class, struct, function, member, etc):

```
/// <summary>
/// fill in your hint here
/// </summary>
public class SomeClass 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prints text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"> String that is printed </param> // param's aren't required though
    public void SomeFunc(string text) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the inline comments attached to those methods in the source code they were compiled from.

If you want to add the same kind of information to your own code, then you can do so. For example you could write

```
/// <summary>  
///  This class performs an important function.  
/// </summary>  
public class MyClass {

   /// <summary>
   /// This method accepts an input string and returns a boolean value depending on what was input
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="input">An arbitrary string value to be evaluated</param>
  /// <returns>A boolean value. If the input value equals "hello" then it will return true. Otherwise, false is returned </returns>
  public bool string MyMethod(string input) {
    if (input == "hello") return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

In Visual Studio, just start typing `///` in the line above your method/class/property declaration and VS will generally auto-complete the declaration for you, and you can just fill in the text.

Once you try to use that method from another section of your code, your comments will be displayed in the intellisense box as you type.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/ for more details.